# JSON to CSV does not skip commas in strings

Tags: javascript, csv

I want to implement JSON to CSV on my server but I am facing an issue with entries that contain commas, as comma is my separator.

This result in some content not being in the corresponding columns.

How can I skip commas when they are in an entry thus in a string.

Thanks

```
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
    var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

data = args.data || null;
if (data == null || !data.length) {
    return null;
}

columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

result = '';
result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
result += lineDelimiter;

data.forEach(function (item) {
    ctr = 0;
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

        result += item[key];
        ctr++;
    });
    result += lineDelimiter;
});
return result;
}


function downloadCSV(args) {
var data, filename, link;
var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
    data: activitesExport
});
if (csv == null) {
    console.log("CSV null");
    return;
}

filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
}
data = encodeURI(csv);

link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', data);
link.setAttribute('download', filename);
link.click();
}
```

A sample of how my data looks like :

`{
"-LSKp07UQ7TAEXYxK6Li" : {
    "activiteId" : "-LSKp07UQ7TAEXYxK6Li",
    "adresseCodePostal" : "38340",
    "adresseVille" : "VOREPPE",
    "adresseVoie" : " 517 rue de Nardan",
    "ageMaximum" : "",
    "ageMinimum" : "",
    "categorie" : "CULTURE",
    "description" : "l’Arrosoir est un équipement destiné à accueillir de nombreux événements festifs et culturels tout au long de l’année.",
    "divers" : "",
    "horaires" : "Horaires divers en fonction des événements",
    "illustration" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
    "indoor" : true,
    "latitude" : 45.2916646,
    "longitude" : 5.6349276,
    "nom" : "L’arrosoir",
    "outdoor" : false,
    "siteWeb" : "",
    "tarifs" : "En fonction de la manifestation",
    "telephone" : "0476504747"
  },
  "-LSKpWYf9fPaBjtU578e" : {
    "activiteId" : "-LSKpWYf9fPaBjtU578e",
    "adresseCodePostal" : "38340",
    "adresseVille" : "VOREPPE",
    "adresseVoie" : "Rue Jean Achard,",
    "ageMaximum" : "",
    "ageMinimum" : "",
    "categorie" : "LOISIRS",
    "description" : "Deux terrains de 4 jeux pour la boule lyonnaise ou la pétanque.",
    "divers" : "",
    "horaires" : "Accès libre ",
    "illustration" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
    "indoor" : false,
    "latitude" : 45.296335,
    "longitude" : 5.6363899,
    "nom" : "Gradins de la verronière",
    "outdoor" : true,
    "siteWeb" : "https://www.voreppe.fr/article/terrains-de-boule",
    "tarifs" : "gratuit",
    "telephone" : "0476504747"
  }
}`

Comment: There are only two simple solutions, first is to re-export the csv with other character as delimiter and second is to use some of already existing libs for csv conversion like papaparse.

Comment: Just enclose each value/field in double-quotes

Comment: Need sample data with all of your boundary conditions.

Comment: I edited my question to add a sample of data

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something very similar with big data text rows
I'd suggest using this library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-stringify

Here's a function i wrote to create a CSV from 'dirty' arrays using csv-stringify

```
export const convertToCSV = (output: string[][]) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve,fail) => {
        stringify(output, (err, outputData) => {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(outputData as string[][]);
            } else {
                fail(err);
            }
        });
    })
}
```